# Why was the prefix 'anti-' chosen for the terms 'antipassive' and 'anticausative'?

Tags: terminology, semantics, verbs

<sub>Source: *Understanding Semantics* (2 ed, 2013) by Sebastian Löbner</sub>

> [p 137:] The **antipassive** in English consists of demoting the direct object argument by omitting it. It removes the THEME/PATIENT argument from the set of core arguments. English does not mark the antipassive by a different form of the verb, but there are languages that do.
>
> [p 138:] The **anticausative** is a diathesis that removes a causer AGENT from the set of core arguments.

Please aid me to infer the connection with the Passive and Causative diatheses, implied by the use of the prefix 'anti-'.

Comment: The Greek prefix *"anti-"* has two meanings: "against" (the most used one) and "instead of" (a replacement). Can it be that the second one is used here?

Comment: Also bear in mind that this is theoretically-charged terminology; it presupposes many claims about how languages work, and many linguists don't use it. _Ergative_ and _antipassive_ are terms adapted from languages that use a certain type of argument marking, and stretched on the procrustean bed of semantic theory until they seem to fit English, at least if you look the right way.  If you want to know what antipassive means, study an Australian language, not English.

Comment: I'd agree that it's meaningless to talk about antipassives in English.